# How to Merge SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

i want the Output of the Following Query in One row 
i want to merge Below SQL Query

Help me please

```
select  Provider_ID,Circel_ID,count(distinct td_all.ID),t_det.BillNoTemp   from TAPINOUT_DIFFERENCES_ALL td_all
        inner join TransferDetails t_det on td_all.bill_no=t_det.Bill_No
where td_all.bill_no not in (select bill_no from  TAPINOUT_DIFFERENCES_ALL where Status='Open') and  sourcename='TransferDetails'
group by  td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID,t_det.BillNoTemp
 order by td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID

select td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID,TAP_DET.BillNoTemp ,count(distinct td_all.ID)as count  from  TAPINOUT_DIFFERENCES_ALL  td_all
INNER JOIN TAPIN_Details TAP_DET ON td_all.FILENAME=TAP_DET.FLNAME
        where td_all.SOURCENAME='TransferDetails' and td_all.Status='Open'
                    group by td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID,TAP_DET.BillNoTemp  
 order by td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID

select td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID,TAP_DET.BillNoTemp,count(distinct td_all.ID)AS COUNT  from  TAPINOUT_DIFFERENCES_ALL  td_all
inner join TAPIN_Details TAP_DET on td_all.FILENAME=TAP_DET.FLNAME
        where td_all.anb_comments='Invoice Not Found'
                    group by td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID,TAP_DET.BillNoTemp   order by td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID

select td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID,t_det.BillNoTemp,count(distinct td_all.ID)  from  TAPINOUT_DIFFERENCES_ALL td_all
inner join TransferDetails t_det on td_all.bill_no=t_det.Bill_No
        where td_all.anb_comments='IT File not found'
                    group by td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID,t_det.BillNoTemp  order by td_all.Provider_ID,td_all.Circel_ID
```

Comment: Forget that ..i just want to Merge Above Query

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [UNION operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), which lets you append the results of multiple queries into a single result set.

It works like so:

```
SELECT columns FROM tbl1 WHERE criteria

UNION

SELECT columns FROM tbl2 WHERE criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION keyword between statements.

```
SELECT bla, bla2 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT bla3, bla4 FROM table2
```